# How can i use related model scope inside whereHas Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, scope, eloquent-relationship

I have two models. `Task` and `TaskCheck`

in `TaskCheck` i have

```
class TaskCheck extends Model
{
    public function task(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }

    public function owner(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function scopeOwnedBy(Builder $query, int $userId): Builder
    {
        return $query->where('user_id', '=', $userId);
    }
}
```

in `Task` model i have

```
class Task extends Model
{
    public function taskCheck(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TaskCheck::class)->with(['taskState', 'owner']);
    }
}
```

And would like to use something like this:

```
public function scopeHasOwner(Builder $query, int $taskOwnerId): Builder
{
    return $query->whereHas('taskCheck', function ($q) use ($taskOwnerId) {
        $q->hasOwner($taskOwnerId);
    });
}
```

however this throws exception `Call to undefined method App\Models\Task::hasOwner()` as it seems inner query is not aware of Task model.

I know I could use this instead and it works

```
public function scopeHasOwner(Builder $query, int $taskOwnerId): Builder
    {
        return $query->whereHas('taskCheck', function ($q) use ($taskOwnerId) {
            $q->where('user_id', '=', $taskOwnerId);
        });
    }
```

but i would rather not repeat the where clause in every related model, because there are more related models deeper in relationships which would use similar functionality and i would like to have it on one place only.

Comment: your scope in TaskCheck is not hasOwner(), it is ownedBy()

Comment: Oh man. Such simple mistake. Thanks that was it. If ouy send this as answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `TaskCheck` model, you have `ownedBy()` scope, but you called `hasOwner()` in the `whereHas` query.

Change your query to `ownedBy()`

```
$query->whereHas('taskCheck', function ($q) use ($taskOwnerId) {
    $q->ownedBY($taskOwnerId);
});
```